# Есть ли смысл оценивать свою производительность по метрикам?

Tags: метрики

Я имею в виду именно самооценку, а не оценку со стороны, когда руководство, сравнивая метрики одного программиста с другим делает, пытается делать вывод о том, кто продуктивнее. Интуитивно понятно, что, например, вчера хорошо работалось, а сегодня работается не очень. А если так, можно взглянуть на метрики, понять, что работа не ладиться и или передохнуть, или переключиться на другую задачу. Есть ли в этом смысл?

Answer (score 3):

*Сейчас как раз читаю замечательную книжку Peopleware…*

Я думаю, Вы правильно написали: «Интуитивно понятно, что, например, вчера хорошо работалось, а сегодня работается не очень». Разве этого не достаточно, чтобы сделать вывод? Реальная численная оценка производительности нужна для отчётности — это бюрократия. А когда для самого себя, вполне хватает внутренних ощущений.

Answer (score 1):

Почему же, смысл есть. Но не для того, чтобы расставлять приоритеты — это действительно лучше оставить на откуп интуиции. А, например, для того, чтобы в будущем научиться более точно оценивать сроки и объем работы. Я правда не очень представляю, о каких именно метриках идет речь :)